# Set Theory count of sets from another set

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $X$ be the set $\{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10\}$.

Deﬁne the set $R$ by
$R = \{(x, y) \in X \times X \mid \text{$x$ and $y$ have the same remainder when divided by $3$}\}$.

Then the number of elements in $R$ is
(A) $40$ (B) $36$ (C) $34$ (D) $33$.

My Thoughts: three possible remainders
$0== (3,6),(6,9),(3,9)$

$1==(1,4),(4,7),(7,10),(1,10),(1,7),(4,10)$

$2==(2,5),(5,8),(2,8)$

The answer choices are very high. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: You are missing many elements. For example in case of remainder 0,you are missing elements like (6,3),(9,6) etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should also consider tuples that look like $(\color{blue}3,\color{red}3)$, because $\color{blue}3$ and $\color{red} 3$ also have the same remainder when devided by $3$ (or any other integer).  You will need to subdivide your set $X$.

In $X$ we have that

- $3, 6, 9$  have the same remainder,
- $1, 4,7,10$ have the same remainder
- $2,5,8$ have the same remainder.

Now the number of elements in $R$ equals the number of ways we can make $2$-tuples out of these sets.

Comment: @user148176 Do you see how you should calculate the last part?

Comment: so the answer should be (3P2+3)+(4P2+4)+(3P2+3)=34 ?

Comment: @square_one How did you come to this? Why do we get the term $3 \mathrm P 2+3$ for instance?

Comment: @square_one Could you answer me this: If $A=\{a,b,c\}$, how many elements does the set $A\times A$ have?

Comment: it should have nine elements .. and I still get 34 elements as the original answer .. is my answer wrong ?

Comment: Yes it's 34 elements. Because the set $\{3,6,9\}\times\{3,6,9\}$ has $3\times 3=9$, etc. By the way, I see what you did with the $3\mathrm P2+3$ etc. This is also correct.